# Current date time with specific output format

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I need to produce the current date to appear as such "February 24,2014" given these guidelines:

> When the form/page loads:
>
> 1. Create a new instance of the DateTime object
> 2. Set the created DateTime instance to the current date time (use your instance name "=Date.Time();")

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime currentDateTime = Date.Time();
    System.Console.WriteLine(currentDateTime.ToString("MMMMMMMMM dd, yyyy"));
    TodayIsLabel.Text = ("Today is: " + currentDateTime);
}
```

I'm getting an error stating

> The name 'Date' does not exist in current context

I also tried using `DateTime.Now` but it didn't convert to the required format that is being asked. It also seems being required to use "=Date.Time();" is not a valid format so I'm not sure if its a typo or not.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` *is* what you want, but that will be the local time on the server (server time zone). You say it "didn't convert to the required format" - what did it do? Note that you should have "MMMM" rather than "MMMMMMMMM".

Comment: It came out as 2/24/2014 with the time. Also part of the instructions from the professor were to use 9 M's to accommodate for september being 9 letters. Im just trying to follow the directions I was given!

Comment: It wouldn't come out that way from the `Console.WriteLine` code you've got. It *would* come out that way in the `TodayIsLabel.Text` property setter you've got, because you're just implicitly calling ToString. It sounds like your professor needs to read MSDN though... you don't need "as many Ms as are in the month name" which is what it sounds like he thinks.

Comment: Okay so how should I output to that label without changing the form from the console.writeline?

Comment: You can call `ToString` in your `Text` setter in exactly the same way as you do the `Console.WriteLine` call...

Comment: Yes.  See the line:  TodayIsLabel.Text = "Today is: " + currentDateTime.ToString( "MMMM dd, yyyy" );  in my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
      DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
      System.Console.WriteLine( currentDateTime.ToString( "MMMM dd, yyyy" );
```

You will also want:

```
TodayIsLabel.Text = "Today is: " + currentDateTime.ToString( "MMMM dd, yyyy" );
```

To see the full list of formats look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

MMMM - The full name of the month.

There is no such thing where you put more than four M's (one for each letter in the month name).  That wouldn't work because you don't always know how many letters are in the current month name.